# translate my containers starter file to docker-compose.yml

Tags: bash, docker, hadoop, docker-compose

I am newer in big data domain, and this is my first time using Docker. I just found this amazing project: https://kiwenlau.com/2016/06/26/hadoop-cluster-docker-update-english/  which create a **hadoop cluster** composed of one master and two slaves using Docker.

After doing all the installation, I just run containers and they work fine. There is  **start-containers.sh** file which give me the hand to lunch the cluster. I decide to install some tools like sqoop to import my local relational data base to Hbase, and that's work fine. After that I stop all Docker container in my pc by tapping

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

In the second day, when I tried to relaunch containers by running the same script **./start-container.sh** , I found this error:

> start hadoop-master container...
>
> start hadoop-slave1 container...
>
> start hadoop-slave2 container...
>
> Error response from daemon: Container
>
> e942e424a3b166452c9d2ea1925197d660014322416c869dc4a982fdae1fb0ad is
>   not running

**even, I lunch this daemon; containers of my cluster cannot connect to each other, and I can't access to data which is stored on Hbase.**

First can any one tell me why this daemon don't work.

PS: in the **start-container.sh** file there is a line which removes containers if they exist before creating them, I delete this line because If I don't delete them, every time I do all things from the beginning.

After searching I found that is preferable to use the **docker compose** which give me the hand to lunch all container together.

But I can't found **how to translate my start-container.sh file to docker-compose.yml file**. Is this the best way to lunch all my containers in the same time ? This is the content of start-containers.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo docker network create --driver=bridge hadoop

# the default node number is 3
N=${1:-3}


# start hadoop master container
#sudo docker rm -f hadoop-master &> /dev/null
echo "start hadoop-master container..."
sudo docker run -itd \
                --net=hadoop \
                -p 50070:50070 \
                -p 8088:8088 \
        -p 7077:7077 \
        -p 16010:16010 \
                --name hadoop-master \
                --hostname hadoop-master \
                spark-hadoop:latest &> /dev/null



# sudo docker run -itd \
#       --net=hadoop \
#       -p 5432:5432 \
#       --name postgres \
#       --hostname hadoop-master \
#       -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=0000
#       --volume /media/mobelite/0e5603b2-b1ad-4662-9869-8d0873b65f80/postgresDB/postgresql/10/main:/var/lib/postgresql/data  \
#       sameersbn/postgresql:10-2 &> /dev/null



# start hadoop slave container
i=1
while [ $i -lt $N ]
do
#    sudo docker rm -f hadoop-slave$i &> /dev/null
    echo "start hadoop-slave$i container..."
    port=$(( 8040 + $i ))
    sudo docker run -itd \
            -p $port:8042 \
                    --net=hadoop \
                    --name hadoop-slave$i \
                    --hostname hadoop-slave$i \
                    spark-hadoop:latest &> /dev/null
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done 

# get into hadoop master container
sudo docker exec -it hadoop-master bash
```

Comment: To me it is a bit unclear what this question is about: Is it about some problems with starting up the cluster (as described in the beginning) or rather about the creation of a docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: @linux-fan I have two questions the first one "how to fix the starting problem for the docker, exactly why in the first time all containers works and in the second time I have an error" my second question is " it is better to run containers using docker-compose? If it is, how to create a docker-compose.yml from my starter script"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problems with restarting containers

I am not sure if I understood the mentioned problems with restarting containers correctly. Thus in the following, I try to concentrate on potential issues I can see from the script and error messages:

When starting containers without `--rm`, they will remain in place after being stopped. If one tries to `run` a container with same port mappings or same name (both the case here!) afterwards that fails due to the container already being existent. Effectively, no container will be started in the process. To solve this problem, one should either re-create containers everytime (and store all important state outside of the containers) or detect an existing container and start it if existent. With names it can be as easy as doing:

```
if ! docker start hadoop-master; then
    docker run -itd \
                --net=hadoop \
                -p 50070:50070 \
                -p 8088:8088 \
                -p 7077:7077 \
                -p 16010:16010 \
                --name hadoop-master \
                --hostname hadoop-master \
                spark-hadoop:latest &> /dev/null
fi
```

and similar for the other entries. Note that I do not understand why one would
use the combination `-itd` (interactive, assign TTY but go to background) for
a service container like this? I'd recommend going with just `-d` here?

Other general scripting advice: Prefer `bash -e` (causes the script to stop on unhandled errors).

## Docker-Compose vs. Startup Scripts

The question contains some doubt whether `docker-compose` should be the way to go or if a startup script should be preferred. From my point of view, the most important differences are these:

- Scripts are good on flexibility: Whenever there are things that need to be detected from the environment which go beyond environment variables, scripts provide the needed flexibility to execute commands and to be have environment-dependently. One might argue that this goes partially against the spirit of the isolation of containers to be dependent on the environment like this, but a lot of Docker environments are used for testing purposes where this is not the primary concern.
- `docker-compose` provides a few distinct advantages "out-of-the-box". There are commands `up` and `down` (and even radical ones like `down -v --rmi all`) which allow environments to be created and destroyed quickly. When scripting, one needs to implement all these things separately which will often result in less complete solutions. An often-overlooked advantage is also portability concerns: `docker-compose` exists for Windows as well. Another interesting feature (although not so "easy" as it sounds) is the ability to deploy `docker-compose.yml` files to Docker clusters. Finally `docker-compose` also provides some additional isolation (e.g. all containers become part of a network specifically created for this `docker-compose` instance by default)

## From Startup Script to Docker-Compose

The start script at hand is already in a good shape to consider moving to a `docker-compose.yml` file instead. The basic idea is to define one `service` per `docker run` instruction and to transform the commandline arguments into their respective `docker-compose.yml` names. The [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) covers the options quite thoroughly.

The idea could be as follows:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  hadoop-master:
    image: spark-hadoop:latest
    ports:
     - 50070:50070
     - 8088:8088
     - 7077:7077
     - 16010:16010
  hadoop-slave1:
    image: spark-hadoop:latest
    ports:
     - 8041:8042
  hadoop-slave2:
    image: spark-hadoop:latest
    ports:
     - 8042:8042
  hadoop-slave2:
    image: spark-hadoop:latest
    ports:
     - 8043:8042
```

Btw. I could not test the `docker-compose.yml` file because the image `spark-hadoop:latest` does not seem to be available through `docker pull`:

```
# docker pull spark-hadoop:latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for spark-hadoop, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

But the file above might be enough to get an idea.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solve my problem and also save my life :)